# Laravel 5: Is there a way to list all values of a specific relation attribute from multiple models in a single query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models:

**DropdownValue**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DropdownValue extends Model
{
    protected $table = "dropdown_values";
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        "field_id",
        "value",
    ];

    public function childValues()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("\\App\\Models\\ChildValue", "value_child", "parent_value_id", "child_value_id");
    }
}
```

and **ChildValue** model:

```
class ChildValue extends Model
{
    protected $table = "children_values";
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        "value"
    ];

    public function parentValue()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("\\App\\Models\\DropdownValue", "value_child", "child_value_id", "parent_value_id");
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to get all the `childValues` values from multiple `DropdownValue` models at once using `lists()` method or using an alternative approach but without using any of the looping structures, just a one-line solution, if possible. Something like that:

```
$parent_values = DropdownValue::with("childValues")->get();
$child_values = $parent_values->lists("childValues.value")->all();
```

---

**I'll consider any solution, even if it doesn't fit entirely in my requirements, so feel free to post your thoughts about this.
Thank you in advance!**

Comment: `$parent_values->lists("childValues.value")->all()` is good approach even `pluck` is most appropriate instead of `lists`.

Comment: Actually what you need?

Comment: Might be, but unfortunately nor lists() neither pluck() doesn't return anything. Looks like the relation can't be reached. Tried to put some dummy text instead of childValues.value and the result was exactly the same, there were just some empty items in the returned collection, one for each of the DropdownValue entry from $parent_values.

Comment: As I said, I need to retrieve all the childValues from every DropdownValue in a single collection/array, but without parsing manually each model, if possible. Just need to use the lists() or pluck() methods or some other similar simple approaches but on the relationship attributes instead of the primary model.

Comment: Is `$parent_values->childValues` empty?

Comment: I can't access the childValues relation directly on $parent_values because $parent_values is a collection of multiple models as I used get() for DropdownValue, but each model from $parent_values has the relation childValues in which I have all the child values from the parent value.

Comment: Relational models may be empty. Try by `count($parent_values->pluck('childValues'))` and check `local_key, foriegn_key` for relation.

Comment: Sure, I'll consider that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution for my situation I used this implementation:

```
$parent_values->map(function($item) {
        return $item->childValues->pluck("value", "id")->toArray();
    })->flatten();
```

A bit more complex than I wanted it to be, but it works for the moment. Anyway, I hope someone will find this useful.

I'll be happy to see your solutions as well. ;)